# What are you allowed to do while using the Warlock's Eldritch Master feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, actions, concentration

One of my Warlocks has taken an interesting turn... After casting a spell that required concentration, he used his Eldritch Master feature. Next turn, he cast Eldritch Blast.

This series of turns raises a few questions for me:

1. Can you maintain concentration while using Eldritch Master?
2. Can you take any actions during the one minute of "entreating your patron"?
3. If the answer to either of my questions is no, would I simply not allow said Warlock to use Eldritch Blast (and end his concentration for the spell), or might his patron find the fact he is multitasking while asking for favors offensive, and turn down his request for the spell slots?

The [Eldritch Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchMaster) warlock feature description says:

> At 20th level, you can draw on your inner reserve of mystical power while entreating your patron to regain expended spell slots. You can spend 1 minute entreating your patron for aid to regain all your expended spell slots from your Pact Magic feature. Once you regain spell slots with this feature, you must finish a long rest before you can do so again.

The rules on [concentration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Concentration) state:

> Normal activity, such as moving and attacking, doesn’t interfere with concentration.

But does using this feature count as "normal"? I'm not quite certain on much of this, and I find the Eldritch Master description quite vague. Please help!

Comment: *Eldritch blast* is not concentration and so will not break concentration on the spell he had cast before. Just a small note outside of the core question.

Comment: @BlakeSteel: I think the two parts of that line in #3 are separate; if he can't maintain concentration, concentration on the other spell ends, and if he can't do anything else during the 1 minute, he can't cast Eldritch Blast during that time.

Comment: @V2Blast oh I was interpreting that as a clarification for why OP would not allow warlock to use Eldritch Blast.

Comment: I think it should be noted that _"you spend one minute entreating your patron..."_. One minute is 10 rounds. So I'm curious of a scenario where the caster is willing to spend 10 rounds "entreating" but needs to immediately cast Eldritch Blast.

Answer (score 9):

## RAW, Eldritch Master does not prevent actions or concentration.

1. Because the "Eldritch Master" feature does not say that it requires concentration, it does not, RAW, break concentration.
2. Because the "Eldritch Master" feature does not explicitly disallow you from taking actions during the one minute, RAW you can take actions and cast spells.
3. It is up to the DM to decide what resides outside of normal activity for concentration. Also in "Concentration" (PHB 204), it says:

   > The DM might also decide that certain environmental phenomena, such as a wave crashing over you while you're on a storm-tossed ship, require you to succeed on a DC 10 Constitution saving throw to maintain concentration on a spell.

   Additionally, the Patron might find offense, but it could easily also be *more* inclined to help if their magical investment is in great danger at the time that they are entreating the patron.

   You should warn your player beforehand if you're going to make "Eldritch Master" affect concentration as an "environmental phenomenon" or if you are going to prevent him from using actions during the entreating of his patron, as both are rulings that are not clear RAW and could affect his actions in combat.

Comment: I'm assuming you quoted concentration's "environmental features" as a way for the DM to factor in the warlock's patron. However, the DC10 CON throw does not fit the circumstances as well as a Persuasion check...thank you for that idea. Additionally, I would like to point out that you have two separate #3 bullets. In regard to the second one, I believe that the attitude of the patron depends on the patron. For example, a Fiend with many warlocks might be more annoyed than a Fey who has only this one.

Comment: That was thrown in to show a way that concentration *could* be involved in entreating your patron if the DM really wanted. Any persuasion checks are DM purview

Comment: But you Spend a minute entreating your master. I always assumed it was kinda like praying, and was a really short, sorry rest

Comment: @GarretGang This featture never specifies it requires concentration or that it requires your action each turn. Compare to Longer Casting Times on PHB 202, where it specifies that casting a ritual requires concentration and your action each turn.

Comment: So basically: It would require time in real life (if real life was a fantasy game), but... RAW D&D says no. Thank you!

Comment: @TheCentaur It still requires time, it just doesn't require the mechanical term "concentration" or an action each turn.

Comment: Sorry, meant time to initiate the feature, sort of like a Casting Time. But somehow, it takes one minute to use, but you can take actions and do basically anything usually possible while using it.